# How to use OpenMP with Qt so the application would be still clickable

Tags: c++, qt, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a Qt application with GUI. And I have a button on it. When I click on the button the program computes something in a loop (with OpenMP) and then shows the result with some GUI element(textbox/label/e.t.c).
Is it possible to make the application clickable during these computations (avoid crushing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QThread` (Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) class to create a thread, which will do your computations. The main thread will execute your GUI application and it will be clickable during computations.
You can find a simple example in documentation for creating your thread:

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }
signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &s);
};

void MyObject::startWorkInAThread()
{
    WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread(this);
    connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::resultReady, this, &MyObject::handleResults);
    connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
    workerThread->start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try [QCoreApplication::processEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents)

> You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation (e.g. copying a file).